# Azure Mobile Services nuget won't install in new VS 2015 project

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to create an Azure Mobile Services cross platform app. I am using Xamarin.Forms, so have been trying to follow [this](http://blog.alectucker.com/post/2014/08/01/azure-mobile-services-with-xamarin-forms.aspx) tutorial. However, I am not getting very far... I create a new Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2015 and opening the nuget manager. I try to install Azure Mobile Services into each project in the solution. But I get the following set of errors:

*Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com. Reason: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Azure_Test, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?   Azure_Test.Droid*

*Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

I have filed a bugzilla case, but it seems like a pretty straight forward thing, so I wondered if there is anything I have done wrong  there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this the other day.  Before you install the Mobile Services package install the Microsoft.Bcl.Build nuget package.  After that, I was able to install flawlessly.